# Why do we need a primary key in table?

Tags: mysql, sql

**Primary key:**

- Used to serve as a unique identifier for each row in a table.
- Cannot accept NULL values.
- Creates clustered index.
- Only one primary key

**Unique key:**

- Used to serve as a unique identifier for a row in a table.
- Can accept one NULL value.
- Creates non-clustered index
- More than one unique key

Almost we are using the primary key to identify each row uniquely so the unique key as well.

I am not sure If I am right or wrong, But If we create a unique key with not null constraint would provide almost the same behavior which is provided by the primary key.

**For example:**

```
CREATE TABLE Persons (
   ID int NOT NULL UNIQUE,
   LastName varchar(255) NOT NULL,
   FirstName varchar(255),
   Age int);
```

So why do we really need a primary key, as a unique key can help us achieve whatever we want?

We can also use a unique key as a foreign key to the reference table as well.

Comment: A primary key _is_ a unique key itself. But a unique key is not a primary key. A table could potentially have multiple unique keys.

Comment: “*Only one primary key*” Don’t most RDBMS’ support composite primary keys?

Comment: _Don’t most RDBMS’ support composite primary keys?_ It’s still a primary key though, even if its value is made up of multiple columns’ values.

Comment: @JaypalSodha . . . The primary key is also what you should be using for foreign key references.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff, appreciate you point, but unique key can also be used as foreign key reference.

Comment: It simplifies how a tables is interacted with, which makes it more maintainable. They are used by ORM frameworks as well.

Comment: In SQL Server the UNIQUE constraint allows for one NULL value, but the PRIMARY KEY does not allow NULL values.

Comment: Yes, @Andrey Belykh, As I have mentioned in the question, we can create our column with not null constraint would work like a primary key only right.

Comment: Who says we "need" one? On what edict (and from whom) is your question based?

Answer (score 2):

A lot of relational purists regard the elevation of one key as the "primary key" as a mistake<sup>1</sup> and believe that all candidate keys should be treated equally. If you're of that school of thought (as you appear to be) then you're correct, you don't *need* a PK.

---

<sup>1</sup>In the design of SQL itself, in having this feature.

Similarly, theorists see no problem with keys consisting of zero columns (a table with that key declared does make sense, and can only contain 0 or 1 row). But here SQL will prevent you from declaring such a key.

Answer (score 1):

It's true that a UNIQUE KEY on NOT NULL column(s) does fill the same role as a PRIMARY KEY.

Folks should remember that a primary key is a constraint, and may be defined on multiple columns. Primary key does not have to be a single-column auto-inc integer.

In MySQL's InnoDB engine, the table is stored as a clustered index by its primary key, or if it doesn't have a primary key, then it's a clustered index by its *first non-null unique key.* (a table can have multiple unique keys). See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-index-types.html

But isn't it quicker and more clear to say the clustered index is by the primary key? :-)

Answer (score 1):

There is a semantic difference.

Ignoring the minor differences such as handling of `NULL`'s, a primary key is essentially a unique constraint, but is simply designated as *the primary one*.  It's the one true way to identify a given row.  If I had a particular row that I wanted you to see, what would I tell you about the row to make sure you look at the exact same row?  I'd tell you the primary key.  "Hey, I think we have a problem with row # 78.  Can you look at row # 78?"  There might be other unique constraints on the table, but the PK is the go-to.

The primary key is the *canonical* identification of a row.  It might be a single column or a combination of columns.  It is entirely possible, valid, and common, to have a primary key and no unique constraints.

**Practical Considerations**

1. Anecdotally, foreign keys very often map rows across tables and therefore the primary key of a table is likely to be repeated across tables.  When doing an update of the value, therefore, foreign keys get impacted.  Due to this, it is often desirable to have an immutable primary key.  So-called *surrogate keys* are popular for this reason, though there are schools of thought on that subject. [1]
2. Documentation tools typically inspect primary keys and foreign keys in order to determine the relationships between tables.  For example, you can auto-generate an ER diagram by traversing the FK to PK relationships.

[1] With that said, keep in mind that foreign keys can point to any column of any table, including the same table.  Pointing to the primary key of a table is extremely common because it usually makes the most sense, but there are cases where it does not make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Although of similar definitions, they have different applications. The primary key is a column that serves to uniquely identify each tuple in the table. Furthermore, it adds integrity constraints to the table and maintains the relationship with foreign keys. The unique key is simpler, it only serves to uniquely identify a tuple in the table.

Comment: It depends on the implementation. In InnoDB, you can define a foreign key that references the non-null columns of a unique key as well as a primary key.

Comment: I don't think this is correct.  Primary keys do not do anything special in terms of foreign keys.

Comment: A primary key of one table can be referenced by foreign key of another table.

Comment: @GustavoM.MendesdeTarso - as can a unique key of another table. There's a reason you're allowed to supply column lists in FK declarations. It wouldn't be necessary/desirable if you could only reference the PK.

Comment: AFAIK, a foreign key of a table can reference any column of any table, even itself.  Maybe MySQL is different than other RDBMS's in this regard?

Comment: @Brandon - usually, for implementation efficiency, you're limited to columns which are covered by an index. And PKs and UKs do create such indices as an implementation detail.

Comment: @Brandon . . . Your understanding is incorrect.  In most databases, a foreign key reference can only be to a `unique` column (which includes primary keys).  MySQL extends this to any indexed column, unfortunately.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Unique, sure, but not primary key.  Same with MS SQL Server and Postgres: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/c499ce66-0bb8-4e4a-adc0-5b720109adc4/can-a-non-primary-key-be-referenced-as-foriegn-key-in-other-table?forum=transactsql.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/sql-createtable.html

As it happens, most foreign keys tend to point to primary keys, but I have never seen that actually be a rule.  It just very frequently ends up making sense.